# vb.net: play audio when button is clicked

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

is there a way to play a audio/music every time the button is click?I use this code to play audio `mciSendString("play " & musicAlias, CStr(0), 0, 0)`.I want to play it every time the button is click. I already put it in the button but the problem is its only play ones.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of audio file is it? .mp3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10s of googling gives you several answers..

For wave-files(.wav) you can simply use `My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Kalimba.wav.")`

MP3-files are a bit more complicated, even more if you dont want to use the WMP controll element.

[Here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?691225-Playing-audio-(-wav-mp3)-without-media-player-control) you have another post with the same requests as you have. And there are several SO posts with the same topic.

Comment: tnx sir. It worked, it is possible to play it from the start everytime button is click?because its only play ones.

Comment: what event are you using? With the normal `Click` event, the music should start over every time you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

i got it sir and its work like what i want.

```
 Private Sub playSound()      
 Dim Mytone As New System.Media.SoundPlayer 

    Mytone.SoundLocation = "audio.wav"
    Mytone.Load()
    Mytone.Play()

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cexitButton.Click 

 playsound()

End Sub
```